# How to get all columns that use column level encryption in a table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I have encrypted a column in my SQL server table using the below article

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-column-level-encryption-decryption-in-sql-server-2016/

Now, I want to get a list of all the columns that are using column-level encryption in a table.

Is there any way to get a list of columns?

Comment: Have a look at `sys.columns`.

Comment: I have checked sys.columns and sys.all_columns but nothing there.

Comment: have a look again, there's columns about the encryption types [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)